# NSPredicate to fetch dictionary from array of arrays

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

From the following array I want to fetch dictionary with  message_id = 1. Basically I want to get the indexpath of the cell whose message_id == 1.

```
<__NSArrayM 0x17d918d0>(
<__NSArrayM 0x17faa070>(
{
    chatStatus = sent;
    date = "Feb 05, 2016";
    from = "";
    height = "17.000000";
    isOutgoing = yes;
    "message_id" = "1";
    time = "02:39 PM";
    to = "";
    width = "95.000000";
},
{
    chatStatus = sent;
    date = "Feb 05, 2016";
    from = "";
    height = "17.000000";
    isOutgoing = yes;
    "message_id" = "2";
    time = "02:39 PM";
    to = "";
    width = "95.000000";
},
)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look around the NSArray's method

```
-[NSArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)]
```

by doing something like that :

```
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

    [myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger firstIndex, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        NSArray *messages = (NSArray*)obj;

        NSIndexSet *indexes = [messages indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            NSDictionary *message = (NSDictionary*)obj;

            if (message.message_id == 1) {
                return YES;
            }
            return NO;

        }];

        [indexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:firstIndex]];

        }];

    })];
```

It's seems a bit tricky, and I did it quickly so that I think you could improve it. The idea is to enumerate through your first array, and then use "indexesOfObjectsPassingTest" to get all indexes for your matching objects. And then you and your indexPaths by going through the enumeration of the NSIndexSet object :)

I think you could even do it recursively, so that you won't be limited by the depth of your arrays which is, here, only 2 :/

Hope it helped \o
Bilkix.